# Prototype /jQuery no conflict IE8 problem with lightview and rotator

Tags: internet-explorer-8, prototypejs, jquery

I managed to use the noconflict solutions. Everything is working great, except in IE8... I discovered that 90% change it is the javascript on the php itself. I changed the $( to jQuery(. This change made everything work in all other browsers... anyone have a solutions for this? Also tried changing place of the scripts, but doesn't do anything. Using Lightview and Rotator.

url => http://www.tdesigns.be/projects/maes-boons/designmeubelen.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="1 week" />
<meta name="language" content="nl"  />
<meta name="keywords" content=""/>
<meta name="description" content="maes-boons nv - meesters in maatwerk"/>
<title>maes-boons</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/960.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/wt-rotator.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.wt-rotator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( 
            function() {
                jQuery(".container").wtRotator({
                    width:960,
                    height:400,
                    button_width:24,
                    button_height:24,
                    button_margin:5,
                    auto_start:true,
                    delay:5000,
                    play_once:false,
                    transition:"fade",
                    transition_speed:800,
                    auto_center:true,
                    easing:"",
                    cpanel_position:"inside",
                    cpanel_align:"BR",
                    timer_align:"top",
                    display_thumbs:true,
                    display_dbuttons:true,
                    display_playbutton:true,
                    display_numbers:true,
                    display_timer:true,
                    mouseover_pause:false,
                    cpanel_mouseover:false,
                    text_mouseover:false,
                    text_effect:"fade",
                    text_sync:true,
                    tooltip_type:"image",
                    lock_tooltip:true,
                    shuffle:false,
                    block_size:75,
                    vert_size:55,
                    horz_size:50,
                    block_delay:25,
                    vstripe_delay:75,
                    hstripe_delay:180           
                });
            }
        );
</script>
<script> 
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightview.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.2/scriptaculous.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightview.js"></script>


</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put all jQuery in a `.ready()` function if you use [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). I don't get an error in IE8 or Chrome12 with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>maes-boons</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tdesigns.be/projects/maes-boons/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tdesigns.be/projects/maes-boons/js/jquery.wt-rotator.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".container").wtRotator({
                width:960,
                height:400,
                button_width:24,
                button_height:24,
                button_margin:5,
                auto_start:true,
                delay:5000,
                play_once:false,
                transition:"fade",
                transition_speed:800,
                auto_center:true,
                easing:"",
                cpanel_position:"inside",
                cpanel_align:"BR",
                timer_align:"top",
                display_thumbs:true,
                display_dbuttons:true,
                display_playbutton:true,
                display_numbers:true,
                display_timer:true,
                mouseover_pause:false,
                cpanel_mouseover:false,
                text_mouseover:false,
                text_effect:"fade",
                text_sync:true,
                tooltip_type:"image",
                lock_tooltip:true,
                shuffle:false,
                block_size:75,
                vert_size:55,
                horz_size:50,
                block_delay:25,
                vstripe_delay:75,
                hstripe_delay:180
            });
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tdesigns.be/projects/maes-boons/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.2/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tdesigns.be/projects/maes-boons/js/lightview.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast look. I changed the js. IE8 still doens't show the rotator images. He gives me a weird error:
object doesn't support this property method
jquery.wt-rotator.js        line1123
Code: 0                         char:5
uri: http://www.tdesigns.be/projects/maes-boons/js/jquery.wt-rotator.js

Do you have any idea how to fix this? 
@andyb.

Comment: I've just checked the source of your page and there are 2 `.noConflict()` statements still. I think that you need to remove the second one.

Comment: I used this line of code and everything now is working perfect.
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

Many thanks for helping!!!